# cannot add button in lavavel backpack controller exeption view not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

flowing the doc in laravel backpack i wnated to add a specifique button beside the create button 
heer : https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-buttons

i created a updatem.blade.php for my button
[image]

then i declared my button as flow :

$this->xPanel->addButton('top', 'view','ok','updatem', 'end');

xpanel replaced Crud :
but i keep getting the folowing error

> ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>   View [updatem] not found. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/smm/packages/larapen/admin/src/resources/views/panel/inc/button_stack.blade.php) (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/smm/packages/larapen/admin/src/resources/views/panel/inc/button_stack.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$this->crud->addButtonFromView('top', 'ok', 'updatem', 'end');
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the 2nd and 3rd arguments reversed
This should work too.

$this->xPanel->addButton('top', 'ok', 'view', 'updatem', 'end');